# How do I show these two algebras are not isomorphic- $K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}$ and $M_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

We have a definite quaternion algebra $K$, we have to show that it is ramified at $\infty$.

For any prime $p$ including $\infty$, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be it's $p$-adic completion if $p$ is finite and $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty} = \mathbb{R}$. We say a quaternion algebra $K$ splits at $p$ if 
$$ K \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_p  \cong M_2(\mathbb{Q}_p )$$
 Here, $\alpha^{2} , \beta^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $<0$, $\alpha. \beta = - \beta. \alpha$
otherwise we say $K$ is ramified at $p$.

(This isomorphism is algebra isomorphism)

Now, here for $K= \mathbb{Q} + \mathbb{Q} \alpha + \mathbb{Q} \beta + \mathbb{Q} \alpha. \beta $, and $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty} = \mathbb{R}$ and

$$ K \otimes \mathbb{R} = (\mathbb{Q} + \mathbb{Q} \alpha + \mathbb{Q} \beta + \mathbb{Q} \alpha. \beta) \otimes \mathbb{R}$$

$$= (\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{R}) +  (\mathbb{Q} \alpha \otimes \mathbb{R}) +  (\mathbb{Q} \beta \otimes \mathbb{R}) +  (\mathbb{Q} \alpha. \beta \otimes \mathbb{R})$$

$$= \mathbb{R} + \alpha (\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{R}) + \beta (\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{R}) + \alpha. \beta (\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{R})$$

$$\cong \mathbb{R} + \alpha \mathbb{R} +\alpha \mathbb{R} + \alpha. \beta \mathbb{R} $$

And $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ on the right side. I know I have to show that these two algebras are not isomorphic. The hint says that  $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ has zero divisors and since $K \otimes \mathbb{R}$ is a division algebra, it does not.
Hence, they cannot be algebra isomorphic.

Is my solution correct?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t think your algebra has zero divisors.

Comment: The sum is only in the sense of vector spaces not algebras since the multiplication is not component-wise. You need to show that in $K \otimes \mathbb{R}$ every element has an inverse. For that it is enough to show that a certain quadratic form has no zeros...

Comment: What is your definition of definite? For me, this means that $K$ is ramified at $\infty$ which makes the answer immediate.

Comment: @Sebastian: I have edited my post a little bit after some discussion with a friend, can you check if it's correct?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think you have really started on a solution, yet, so it's premature to ask whether it is correct. Now try to proceed with the hint. What Sebastian was getting at is for you to mimic the proof for the fact that that non-zero Hamiltonian quaternions are invertible. In that case the proof heavily relies on $\alpha^2=-1=\beta^2=(\alpha\beta)^2$ and the formula
$$(r_1+r_2\alpha+r_3\beta+r_4\alpha\beta)(r_1-r_2\alpha-r_3\beta-r_4\alpha\beta)=r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2+r_4^2.$$ And the claim follows from basic properties of squares of real numbers.

Comment: In a more general case the product will have a slightly more complicate right hand side, but the same conclusion can be made.

Comment: Anyway, the claim is false in general unless we assume $\alpha^2<0$ and $\beta^2<0$, and any solution should reflect that. Bluntly, if you don't use $\alpha^2<0$ and $\beta^2<0$, you have missed the boat.